# how to enable username and password autofill in browsers

Tags: jquery, html, autofill

i have login page where in which i want to autofill username and password fields once user logged in first. so next time if he comes back to login page the username and password field need to be autofilled so he just clicks login button.

i have autocomplete enabled above fields, but it doesnt work in IE or chrome browsers.

```
<input type="text"  id="userName" autofocus="autofocus" value="" tabindex="1" autocomplete="on">

 <input type="password"  name="password" id="password" value="" tabindex="2" maxlength="20" autocomplete="on">
```

Comment: Check your browser settings.. Does it work on other websites you login to?

Comment: yes it works for my facebook and other sites.. wondering any additional step taken to autofill?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add it to the `<form/>` on your page as well.

```
<form autocomplete="on" ..other attributes>
```